# Java Regex to replace string surrounded by non alphanumeric characters

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I need a way to replace words in sentences so for example, "hi, something".  I need to replace it with `"hello, something"`.
`str.replaceAll("hi", "hello")` gives me `"hello, somethellong"`.

I've also tried `str.replaceAll(".*\\W.*" + "hi" + ".*\\W.*", "hello")`, which I saw on another solution on here however that doesn't seem to work either.

What's the best way to achieve this so I only replace words not surrounded by other alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word boundaries should serve you well in this case (and IMO are the better solution).  A more general method is to use negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
 String input = "ab, abc, cab";
 String output = input.replaceAll("(?<!\\w)ab(?!\\w)", "xx");
 System.out.println(output); //xx, abc, cab
```

This searches for occurrences "ab" that are not preceded or followed by another word character.  You can swap out "\w" for *any* regex (well, with practical limitations as regex engines don't allow unbounded lookaround).

Comment: Very nice! 1+ I'm betting that you are familiar with the tutorial site I've linked to.

Comment: @Hovercraft: It's open in another tab right now :P.  But that's because I always forget the syntax of lookahead/lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\b` for word boundaries:

```
String regex = "\\bhi\\b";
```

e.g.,

```
  String text = "hi, something";
  String regex = "\\bhi\\b";
  String newString = text.replaceAll(regex, "hello");

  System.out.println(newString);
```

If you're going to be doing any amount of regular expressions, make this [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) your new best friend. I can't recommend it too highly!

Comment: i cut and paste the code exactly and this is the output "hi, something"

Comment: You want `replaceAll`, not `replace`, as the latter works on literals, not regexes.

Comment: changing to replaceAll as Mark suggested fixes the issue

Comment: @Bruce: dang fat fingers. `replace` changed for `replaceAll`

Comment: otherwise, nice one, i personally learnt something new today +1 :)