# How to remove all number in string except "1" and "2"?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to delete all number in a `String` except number `1` and `2` that stand alone. And then I want to replace `1` with `one` and `2` with `two`.

For example, the input and output that I expect are as follows:

```
String myString = "Happy New Year 2019, it's 1 January now,2 January tommorow";
```

Expected output:

```
myString = "Happy New Year, it's one January now,two January tommorow";
```

So, `1` and `2` in `2019` are deleted, but `1` and `2` that stand alone are replaced by `one` and `two`.

I've tried using regex, but all numbers were erased. Here is my code:

```
public String cleanNumber(String myString){
    String myPatternEnd = "([0-9]+)(\\s|$)";
    String myPatternBegin = "(^|\\s)([0-9]+)";
    myString = myString.replaceAll(myPatternBegin, "");
    myString = myString.replaceAll(myPatternEnd, "");
    return myString;
}
```

I also tried to replace with this regex `[1]` and `[2]` but the `2019` becomes `two0one9`.

I have no idea how to change this `1` and `2` that stand alone. Any recommendations?

Comment: FWIW, the `2` isn't "standing alone". If you're looking for single digits then you should only look for single digits, not one or more.

Comment: Please define "stand alone". Is `1` in `1st place` considered as "alone"?

Comment: also note that your example remove ` 2019`, including a space, not just `2019`, so you really need to first describe this more precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `replaceAll` in this order:

```
myString = myString
          .replaceAll("\\b1\\b", "one") // replace 1 by one
          .replaceAll("\\b2\\b", "two") // replace 2 by two
          .replaceAll("\\s*\\d+", "");  // remove all digits

//=> Happy New Year, it's one January now,two January tommorow
```

Also **it is important to use word boundaries** while replacing `1` and `2` to avoid matching these digits as part of some other number.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two calls to `String#replaceAll` where the regular expression pattern looks for digits on either side of the `1` and `2`:

```
public String cleanNumber(String myString) {
    return myString.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)1(?!\\d)", "one")
                   .replaceAll("(?<!\\d)2(?!\\d)", "two");
}
```

Output:

```
Happy New Year 2019, it's one January now,two January tommorow
```

Inspiration taken from: [Java Regex to replace string surrounded by non alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365419/7294647)

Answer (score 0):

*first replace the one-digit 1's and 2's and afterward delete all other numbers*

```
public String cleanNumber( String s ){
  s = s.replaceAll( "(\\D)1(\\D)", "$1one$2" ).replaceAll( "(\\D)2(\\D)", "$1two$2" );
  return( deleteChars.apply( s, "0123456789" ) );
}

String myString = "Happy New Year 2019, it's 1 January now,2 January tommorow";
cleanNumber( myString );  // Happy New Year , it's one January now,two January tommorow
```

[find deleteChars here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string/56916146#56916146)